# Vagrant rsync is super slow

Tags: vagrant, rsync

I have this in vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant",
type: "rsync", rsync__auto: true, rsync__exclude: [".git/", "django/"]
```

+ I run `vagrant rsync-auto` in separate tab.

After making changes to file it takes vagrant ~5s to pick it up and rsync.

Anyway to speed this up? I am using it for webpack/hot-module-reloading.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slightly outdated plugin called `vagrant-gatling-rsync` which is meant to solve this situation.

https://github.com/smerrill/vagrant-gatling-rsync

You should be able to install it using

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-gatling-rsync
```

You can then (optionally) add this to your Vagrantfile:

```
config.gatling.rsync_on_startup = true
```

The above line should not be needed any more, as this is the default behaviour of the plugin.

You should be able to trigger this functionality by replacing your existing `$ vagrant rsync-auto` command with the matching one from the plugin:

```
$ vagrant gatling-rsync-auto
```

In my personal experience, I have not found any issues with the built-in version of Vagrant's rsync since version `1.9.0` or so, however this may help in your situation.